# Insert data into table1 based on a query from table2

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, insert

[DisneyPassID] and [PersonID]
are the same value and will be coming a different table. 
[MickeyID],[Comment] and [CafeComment] will be the same for all records.

```
table1
[MickeyID],[DisneyPassID],[Comment],[CafeComment],[PersonID] ) 
12    ,    1234,          'test',   'sample',      1234)

table2
[goofID],[GoofPassID],[Comment]
23,       2334,       'blue',  `enter code here`
21,       2311,       'test',  
23,       5432,       'yellow',  
23,       1221,       'test',  
23,       5533,       'blue',  
23,       1223,       'blue',  
21,       2334,       'blue',  
21,       2311,       'test',  
23,       5432,       'yellow',  
23,       1221,       'test',  
25,       5533,       'blue',  
23,       1223,       'yellow',
```

Query for table2. Basically I'm gathering all GoofPassIDs  based on Comment uf they are blue or yellow and goofID 23

```
SELECT GoofPassID
FROM [Space004].[dbo].[table2]
where 
(Comment = 'blue' 
or Comment = 'yellow' 
) 
and goofID = 23
```

will gives me 2334,5432, 5533..etc..

Desired result would be

```
    table1
    [MickeyID],[DisneyPassID],[Comment],[CafeComment],[PersonID] ) 
    12    ,    1234,          'test',   'sample',      1234)
    12    ,    2334,          'test',   'sample',      2334)
    12    ,    5432,          'test',   'sample',      5432)
```

Any ideas on how to write this?

Comment: Where do the different person ids come from? You only show one?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CTE` and create a custom rank column using an integer to always get `table1`'s results above `table2`. Alternatively, you can wrap the entire query in an outer query instead of using a `CTE` (details in my Fiddle below). If you don't care about the table order, you can take the query out of the `CTE`. I've also utilized a `CROSS JOIN` and `UNION`.

```
WITH CTE AS 
    (SELECT 
        1 AS Rank,
        MickyID,
        DisneyPassID,
        Comment,
        CafeComment,
        PersonID
      FROM table1
         UNION
      SELECT
         2 AS Rank,
         a.MickyID, 
         b.GoofPassID AS DisneyPassID, 
         a.Comment, 
         a.CafeComment, 
         b.GoofPassID AS PersonID
      FROM table1 a
      CROSS JOIN table2 b
      WHERE (b.Comment = 'blue' OR b.Comment = 'yellow') AND b.goofID = 23)
SELECT
  MickyID,
  DisneyPassID,
  Comment,
  CafeComment,
  PersonID
FROM CTE
ORDER BY Rank ASC
```

| MickyID | DisneyPassID | Comment | CafeComment | PersonID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 1234 | test | sample | 1234 |
| 12 | 1223 | test | sample | 1223 |
| 12 | 2334 | test | sample | 2334 |
| 12 | 5432 | test | sample | 5432 |
| 12 | 5533 | test | sample | 5533 |

See [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dpldKSBF).